# Make Movie of Matlab SISO tool

Tags: matlab

For my presentation, i need to show the effect of changing the value of a parameter on the position of zeros and polose of the closed loop system. To do so, i am using the sisotool of matlab and everything is fine with my results.

To make the presentation more intressting, i need to make a video out of it such a way that the loop gain sweep between a range and the audiances can see the changes in bode diagram of the closed loop system in a video template. Is there anyway that i can make a movie of the root locus graphs prodcued by sisotool? Basically what i need in practice is to sweep the parameter automatically instead of dragging it. Then i can make a video of the screen.

Thanks :)